# rotate rect in android 2d graphics?

Tags: android, 2d, rotation, rect

i want to rotate a rect(not only draw rotated rect but get the new rotated value ) in android ,i tried

`canvas.rotate`

but it didn't reflect the new values on the rect its just draw a rotated rec.

And this is not helping me because i used the rect in collision detection

**Is there a way to rotate the model of the rect not only draw a rotated one ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i agree with grWEn, try using opengl-es. you can read this blog, it really helped me. 
Here: http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/01/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-iii-%E2%80%93-transformations/

Comment: I appreciate your help ,but i cant stop now and start using opengl i have limited time .The first thing i will do after finishing this app is reading the tutorial u send me and learning opengl-es .Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

openGL ES is a very good library to Android graphics. Rotate a shape is very easy with glRotateF. 
You can find a couple of very useful openGL ES tutorial on the web. This kind of stuff is in basic tutorial.

Comment: android 2d graphics is fit on my app ,so i need to continue use it,i don't want to enter in opengl complexity.